# I am trying to compile a c++ code at visual studio 2010 and i am getting a linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

1>func.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_PathAppendW@8 referenced in function "private: int __thiscall calendar::login(void)" (?login@calendar@@AAEHXZ)
1>c:\users\argaar01\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\calender\Debug\calender.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.

---

i found this code has a comment which says that :-
- to compile add "-lshlwapi" when calling the linker.

But how should i add "-lshlwapi" when calling the linker in visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. Add `shlwapi.lib` to the list there.

Comment: Amazing it worked for me and i never got so fast reply. Thanks a lot!!